# iOS access data from multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, global-variables, tabview

I have an iOS app with multiple views.

A login `UIView` that the user first sees, and upon entering the right credentials, he will then be taken to the main `TabBarViewController`, that 'manages' the rest of the views.

The login `UIView` is connected to the `TabBarViewController` with a modal Segue. I also use this Segue to pass data from the Login view to the `TabBarViewController`, by using properties. All is fine until now.

As mentioned, there are other views, connected to this `TabBarViewController`, and this tab bar only displays them.

The question is, how can I access the property of `TabViewController` (which the loginView sets with a certain value), in other Views ? 
I want to be able to access this property from multiple other views.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use KVO, and when a value is set for a object foo, update display / take action.
another option is to use [self.presentingViewController do stuff];, and trigger an action.
it really depends on the exact flow you wish to create...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you haven't made clear here. I'm assuming that you have subclassed `UITabBarController`.

If all the view controllers are children of the tab bar controller, then `self.tabBarController` will give you access to the tab bar.

It may end up looking something like this:

```
if ([self.tabBarController isKindOfClass:[MyTabBarController class]]) {
    MyTabBarController *myTabBarController = (MyTabBarController *)self.tabBarController;
    // …
}
```

Comment: @user3115488 I feel that I should to tell you, subclassing `UITabBarContorller` to add properties for a data model is not recommended by Apple. You may wish to follow the advice in the other answers: create a singleton data manager or put the data in the appDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

1.Add a property to your AppDelegate, setters and getters will be implemented automatically for you

2.In your other class access the property like so: `id value = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] myGreatProperty];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the same data from different ViewControllers, not UIView I guess, then the best approach is to use a `Singleton` class where you can set and get your desired data/property.

If you do not know how to write Singleton, a good tutorial is [here](http://i-phone-dev.blogspot.com/2013/09/iphone-objective-c-writing-singleton.html?token=T2zCB0MBAAA.SwasoutrEtxYMQZ1KK_8Ow.wm9wtadeP-xiblb3vqywgw&postId=9148443058292576593&type=POST).

Answer (score 0):

Put those data in your Application's Delegate, which is actually a Singleton. The other way is to pass references of your controller to the other controllers that need to access the other's data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create protocol for providing data from your properties. Confirm tab controller to your protocol and implement this protocol's method.
Then in all views declare property with this protocol

`id <YourProtocolName> delegate`

When you create view from your tab controller set tab controller as delegate for created view. After it you can call in views

`[self.delegate access_method_from_protocol]`